# How to hide mountpoints and hosts hardware info from container? what directories are necessary to mount for running game servers in container?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, docker

I'm trying to run some game servers like fivem txAdmin , samp, mta , minecraft and etc on docker,
What directories of the ones that docker mask/mount by default are necessary to mount as read and write for running game servers in container?
Also I'm binding some directories from host to container and when i execute "df -h" on container, i can see which path is volume mounted from in host.
for example : /vol is mounted from /zfspool/dataset on host.
i want to hide or change "/zfspool/dataset"
How can i hide/mask this information from container?
An other thing is:
if i execute "free -m" in container, i get the total memory of the host while the container is limited to 1gb of ram,
Is there a way to hide/correct this to 1gb? Same thing for cpu as well.

An other question i have is :
This containers are going to be controlled and accessed by untrusted users, So far i am limiting the volumes size with ZFS,
Running the process inside container as "container" user,
Using "container" namespace remapping,
Limiting the usage of ram and CPU and memory swap,
PID limit is set to 512,
Everything else is set to default.
What more steps/configurations i need to take in order to make the host machine more secure? And limit the unnecessary permissions/access of the container?

Comment: Please format and capitalise the start of the sentences.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There are at least 3 distinct questions in this question even if they all pertain to use of a container: prevent seeing mounts, detecting correct amount of available RAM and improving security. That's 2 questions too many.